# Weird thing about JSON content output in python

Tags: python, json, file, diff

Forgive me here if this has already been asked. I am seeing some weird results from a simple python code snippet:

```
import json
''' copy contents of one json file into another '''
with open('./new_file.json', 'w') as f1:
    with open('./old_file.json') as f2:
        data = json.load(f2)            
        json.dump(data, f1)
```

The code snippet above copies contents of one json file into the other. The original file does not have pretty formatting (i.e content is all on one line)

After running the code, I then do the following:

```
$ diff -q new_file.json old_file.json
Files new_file.json and old_file.json differ
```

The file contents apparently are different which is strange. 
I then tried to do:

```
$ cat new_file.json | python -m json.tool > foo
$ cat old_file.json | python -m json.tool > bar
```

And then when I do compare the files bar and foo, I get:

```
:~/$ diff -q foo bar
:~/$
```

Which shows that the resulting content after formatting are the same. Is there any explanation for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the json file (or at least a minimal json file reproducing the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json objects are [defined as "an unordered set of name/value pairs"](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), and so are Python dicts (until python 3.7 at least), so the dicts created by `json.load()` can have their keys in a different order. Then when you `json.dump()` those dicts it's the current dicts keys order which is used to generate the json.

example:

```
$ cat old.json
{"a": 42, "c": {"baaz": "quux", "foo": "bar"}, "b": [1, 2, 3]}

$ cat new.json
{"a": 42,  "b": [1, 2, 3], "c": {"foo": "bar", "baaz": "quux"}}

$ diff -q old.json new.json
Les fichiers old.json et new.json sont différents

d$ python
(...)
>>> import json
>>> with open("old.json") as f:
...     old = json.load(f)
>>> with open("new.json") as f:
...     new = json.load(f)
... 
>>> old == new
True
>>>
```

The point is that since the key order is not significant in json, `diff` is not the right tool to check whether two json strings are really different - and their are indeed quite a few tools to do [proper json diff](https://www.google.fr/search?q=json%20diff).

Also as Poshi and Vincent mention, those two json strings are equivalent as json data, while being different as text:

```
{"a": 42, "c": {"baaz": "quux", "foo": "bar"}, "b": [1, 2, 3]}
{"a":42,     "c"     :  {"baaz":"quux"   , "foo": "bar" }   , "b"  : [  1,   2,   3] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You already pointed it out: the file format. One file is only one line, the other maybe have more lines. Spaces can come and go... all of this formatting things makes files different, but the content is essentially the same.

Comment: old_file.json and new_file.json are both on one line, i.e don't have pretty formatting. If the argument is about formatting then I would assume the new_file.json should be the same as foo and bar since three of these files are from python output, however that is not the case.

Comment: `{"foo":"bar"}` is different from `{"foo": "bar"}`. And all is in one line.

Comment: This comment kind of answers my question than the answer itself, "format" meant a lot of things, while "order" which is the reason makes sense.

Comment: You asked for an explanation for your findings, and without seeing the actual json files we can only guess. Format can be an explanation. Ordering can be another explanation. We can only guess your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal re-expression of the behavior you are seeing. Go through it and see if you are still confused about why its `False` for `new==old` but `True` for `foo==bar`. It is almost self explanatory.

```
import json
def tool(jsons):
    return json.dumps(json.loads(jsons))

old = '[{"key": "value"     }]'
new = tool(old)
print(f'{old} == {new}', new == old)
# [{"key": "value"     }] == [{"key": "value"}] False

foo = tool(new)
bar = tool(old)
print(f'{foo} == {foo}', foo == bar)
# [{"key": "value"}] == [{"key": "value"}] True
```

To expand on it. What you are seeing is that running the tool fixes any unneeded formatting. So initially the two files are different. However, since rerunning the tool on something that is already formatted just returns the same result, running the tool on both the old and new file will just reproduce the same output twice, which is the formatted output.